# Public transport (Lynx buses) Orlando, FL - "fixed route" pass

Tags: usa, public-transport, orlando

I visited the [Lynx website](http://www.golynx.com/fares-passes/where-to-buy-passes.stml) but I can't find any information on what the "fixed route" includes. Is it strict in the sense of fixed bus stops or is it more loosely defined as fixed lines?

Specifically, I am planning to use lines ("Link") 8, 38, and 42 for no more than a week. Which bus pass would cover all these lines? I'm lost. Any other recommendation or alternatives for public transport covering Airport/Downtown/International Drive, most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Fixed route* simply refers to regularly scheduled routes, in contrast to services like [NeighborLink](http://www.golynx.com/riding-lynx/neighborlink.stml) or [ACCESS LYNX](http://www.golynx.com/riding-lynx/access-lynx/) which are variable/flexible. In other words, fixed routes include [local scheduled bus service](http://www.golynx.com/riding-lynx/local-bus-service.stml), [express scheduled bus service](http://www.golynx.com/riding-lynx/xpress-bus-service.stml), and [commuter bus service](http://www.golynx.com/riding-lynx/fastlink.stml).

Comment: So I can buy a "Fixed Route 7-Day Standard Pass" and use it across all aforementioned Links unlimited times, for 7 days. Is that right?

Comment: @ilakast Yes, I would expect to be able to use a "fixed route" pass on routes 8, 38, and 42, provided those lines are not specifically excluded in the terms and conditions of the pass.